# Node JS Google Drive api error: The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to upload files to Google Drive using Node JS api. I have enabled Google Drive api and created service account. Then I share one folder with this account. The problem is that I see file I have uploaded using node js, but free space doesn't change when I upload files using api, so I can't monitor how many space left. What is more, when I upload about 7 GB using api this error appered(I have 14 GB free on Google Drive):

```
code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'storageQuotaExceeded',
      message: "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded."
    }
  ]
```

Why can I see this files on Google Drive, but they don't use my Google Drive space? How can I toogle it to use my Google Drive space?

Uploading function:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

const KETFILEPATH = "key.json"


let main_dir_id = "1oT2Fxi1L6iHl9pDNGyqwBDyUHyHUmCJJ"


const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KETFILEPATH,
    scopes: SCOPES
})
let createAndUploadFile = async (auth, file_path, mimeType, folder_id, i = 0) => {
    const driveService = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth })

    let fileMetaData = {
        'name': file_path.slice(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    let media = {
        mimeType: mimeType,
        body: fs.createReadStream(file_path)
    }
    let res = await driveService.files.create({
        resource: fileMetaData,
        media: media,
    })
    if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log('Created file id: ', res.data.id)
        return res.data.id
    } else {
        // this error is in res
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing an https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?

Comment: To which account you are uploading the files? To your regular account or to your service account? If it's the latter, please call [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) using the service account to check how much space you have left.

Comment: @DaImTo Unfortunately  I can't find the way I can use this method using Node JS api

Comment: @lamblichus Am i right, that if I upload files to folder, that I have created in my regular account and I shared with service account, I upload files to regular account? (I specify folder id during uploading)

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code.  Have you tried uploading a smaller file does it go to your personal drive account?

Comment: @DaImTo I uploaded small files. I can see them at my personal drive account, but service account is the owner

Comment: yes you need to update the permissions on the file to make your personal account the owner.  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update  check transfer ownership

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

As you can see at [Share folders in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529), the storage space will be occupied by the account who uploaded the file (that is, the owner of the file), not the owner of the shared folder:

> Storage is counted against the person who uploaded the file, not the owner of the folder.

Therefore, if you try to upload the file with the service account, the file will take storage space in the service account's Drive. That is to say, when you check there are still 14 GB free in your regular account's Drive, you are looking at the wrong place.

#### Possible solutions:

Call [About: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) with your service account to check how much space you have left in that account's Drive. Chances are you can [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) some files in order to free up some storage space.

If that is not a possibility, I'd suggest granting [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to the service account and use that to impersonate your regular account (and upload the files on behalf of it).

Of course, [transfering ownership](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en) of the file would free up space in the service account's Drive, but since you cannot upload the file, I don't think that is a feasible solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I created this tool to delete some files in my service account

https://github.com/quangvinh2080/google-drive-cli

- Set your credentials

```
export GDRIVE_CLIENT_EMAIL=example@email.com
export GDRIVE_PRIVATE_KEY="service account's private key"
```

- Check quota

```
google-drive about:get --fields=storageQuota --rawOutput
```

- List & delete files & empty trash:

```
google-drive files:list
google-drive files:delete --fileId=<fileId>
google-drive files:emptyTrash
```